# call onCreateOptionsMenu in onPostCreate

Tags: android, oncreateoptionsmenu

I want to dynamically change the `onCreateOptionsMenu` items. I have rectified my problem and the only solution is to call `onCreateOptionsMenu` in `onPostCreate` but i don't know how to call it. 
I have already tried my solutions non works. Is it even possible..?

Answer (score 23):

**Changing menu items at runtime (From Docs)**

After the system calls `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, it retains an instance of the `Menu` you populate and will not call `onCreateOptionsMenu()` again unless the menu is invalidated for some reason. However, you should use `onCreateOptionsMenu()` only to create the initial menu state and not to make changes during the activity lifecycle.

If you want to modify the options menu based on events that occur during the activity lifecycle, you can do so in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method. This method passes you the Menu object as it currently exists so you can modify it, such as add, remove, or disable items. (Fragments also provide an `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` callback.)

On Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` each time the user opens the options menu (presses the Menu button).

On Android 3.0 and higher, the options menu is considered to always be open when menu items are presented in the action bar. When an event occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to request that the system call `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

`invalidateOptionsMenu()` was added in API 11 to give us the ability to force onCreateOptionsMenu() to be called again.

[invalidateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu())

**NOTE:**

In case of ICS and Honeycomb `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called after `onCreate()` and `onPostCreate()` while in Gingerbread and earlier versions it is called after `onCreate()` but before `onPostCreate()`.

Try following:

```
public static void refreshMenu(Activity activity)
{
    activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Answer (score 17):

use this,

invalidateOptionsMenu ();

Comment: Can you please give me an example..?

Comment: when you call invalidateOptionMenu, it again calls onCreateOptionsMenu and then you have to handle what you want to do in onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: oh okay.. but where should i call InvalidateOptionsMenu(); ? the function that filling the optionsmenu is another java file and is fetching data from a web service.The problem is the delay.. if i toggle a break point and produce a delay then the whole thing is working fine..

Comment: invalidateOptionMenu is used to upldate the optionMenu and you can call it anywhere.